DB Concurrency Rate Limiting
I am working on a java based multi-tenant architecture. So multiple customer data will be stored in a single MySql DB. Now in DB level (InnoDB), we have set innodb_thread_concurrency value as 20. Hence only 20 parallel request will be served at any instance by MySQL. Each query can execute from 0ms to 5 mins. The problem is how can I set customer wise concurrency limit in this case. Also how can I split my thread across each bucket (bucket means 1 - 10ms query as one bucket, 11 - 100 ms query as second bucket, and so on).
I have collected number of parallel request served by each DB at an instance (each ms) for a period of 10 minutes. I have also collected execution time of each query. From this data, we can infer how many 0ms, 1ms and so on.... queries has been served by the DB at any instance.
With these data, how can I derive concurrency limit. Kindly suggest any formula or any alternative approaches to deduce the same.

Mysql is not aware your customers, so concurrency must either be limited at application level or every customer must have their own unique mysql user account where you can limit the concurrent mysql connections a user can make. Unless you can predict how long a query is likely to take, not sure how you can bucket them up.

Also, a thread servers a connection, so all queries through a connection will be executed by the same thread.  So, on database level, your connections either serve a client (you can do concurrency limit by client) or they can serve certain type of queries, but you cannot do both.

The rate limiting logic will be implemented in java level only. Also before executing a query, consider I already have a list which contains query vs time. So chosing the bucket at runtime won't be a issue.
But here I need to know how many I can parallely allow to get connection and query DB.

I don't think we can suggest you a formula to calculate concurrency constraints as we do not know the pattern of usage. You need to do stress testing to see if your infrastructure is capable of handling the peak loads you are expecting.

Thats the problem here. Since there are n number of customers, with each customer having their own load, how can I come with a common limit? Is there any alternative approaches for the same. Assume I have taken number of queries executed per ms for 2 highly used customers
